# Optimizing curvature of $\frac{\sin(x)}x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

At what point along the curve does the graph of $y=\frac{\sin(x)}x$ have the smallest curvature?

I've tried computing this with a bunch of derivatives but I don't think it's meant to be solved that way

Comment: You've tagged this with `multivariable-calculus` but the function shown seems to be univariate (one variable).  There are a variety of ways to define [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) as a numeric value, all related to the second derivative in one-dimension.  Definitions are our friends.  Please specify how the curvature is defined so we can help evaluate it.

Comment: In fact, I did not need so much blabla ! The curvature is minimum when $|y''|=0$ that is to say when $y''=0$. End of the story.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that we could have an explicit solution.

Let
$$y=\frac{\sin(x)}x \implies y'=\frac{x \cos (x)-\sin (x)}{x^2}\implies y''=-\frac{\left(x^2-2\right) \sin (x)+2 x \cos (x)}{x^3}$$ Minimizing
$$\kappa = \frac{|y''|}{\left(1+(y')^2\right)^\frac32}$$ is the same as minimizing $\kappa ^2$ and $$\frac {d\kappa ^2}{dx}=\frac{2 y'' \left(y''' \left(1+(y')^2\right)-3 y'
   (y'')^2\right)}{\left(1+(y')^2\right)^4}$$ So, *one* solution corresponds to $y''=0$ (in fact, if you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)), you will notice the approximation $\kappa\approx y''$) and then we need to solve for $x$
$$\left(x^2-2\right) \sin (x)+2 x \cos (x)=0$$ that is to say to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\left(x^2-2\right) \sin (x)+2 x \cos (x)$$ If you graph this function or use inspection, you will notice that there is a root close to $x_0=\frac{2 \pi }{3}$. So, let us use Newton method to get the following iterates
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{\left(x_n^2-2\right) (x_n-\tan (x_n))}{x_n^2}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.094395102 \\
 1 & 2.081795781 \\
 2 & 2.081576044 \\
 3 & 2.081575978
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

You could skip the Newton part building a series expansion close to $x_0$. This would give
$$y''=\left(\sqrt{3}+\frac{2 \pi }{3}-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{2}{9} \pi
   ^2 \left(x-\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{2 \pi
   }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ and, ignoring the higher order terms, this would give the estimate
$$x=\frac{2 \pi }{3}-\left(\frac{9 \sqrt{3}}{2 \pi ^2}+\frac{3}{\pi }-\sqrt{3} \right)\approx 2.08180$$

We could have a still better approximation if, instead of using Taylor series, we build the $[1,1]$ Padé approximant of $f(x)$ around $x=\frac{2 \pi }{3}$. This would lead to
$$x=\frac{2 \pi }{3}+\frac{2 \pi  \left(9 \sqrt{3}+6 \pi -2 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2\right)}{27 \sqrt{3}+45 \pi
   -10 \pi ^3}\approx 2.08158$$